# Neo4j Java register gds.alpha.shortestPath.stream to embedded neo4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j

i want to use the graph data science shortestPath algorithm in my embedded neo4j instance.

Does anyone know which dependencies i need for that and how i can register the procedure then in my spring neo4j application? I have found different solutions, but it seems like none of them work anymore and are deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

What version of neo4j are you using ?

1.Download the appropriate jar file based on this table
https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science

2 : Check your plugins folder which can be found in neo4j.conf

3. Place the jar file in the plugins folder
4. Restart Neo4j
5. Check if the plugin registered by running the following cypher
   RETURN gds.version()